# PHP: switch with multiple conditions, a better more elegant way?

Tags: php

This is my current code, where if a given string starts with a specific letter
I fire a function... simple...

```
      switch ($string[0]) {
        case 'a':
            //do   X
            break;
        case 'b':
             //do   Y
            break;
        case 'c':
            //do   Z
            break;
        case 'd':
            //do   X
            break;
//
// etc etc with all alphabet
//
        default:
            //do some
            break;
    }
```

but i'd like to fire a function X, if both a, b and c is met, and function Y if another group of letters match the conditions...

im wondering if there is a more elegante way to do it instead of a 26 letters switch..

I think i need to use `preg_match`, but not sure how...

Comment: 1) You could use an array and use keys as letters and values as function names as long as you don't do some complicated function calling 2) *if both a, b and c is met* is `$string[0]` now a string with multiple characters or just a single one?!

Comment: depending on how branchy this gets a regex might be easier to do `if(preg_match('/^[abc]/','atest')) echo "fizz";`

Comment: is it possible to have something like case (preg_match(...)...)...

Comment: you can combine the `case` statements, ie `case 'A': case 'B': case 'C': /*do stuff*/ break;`

Comment: Whoever is downvoting this question, please leave a comment explaining. I don't see anything wrong with the question. It clearly states a problem, supplies code and asks for suggested improvements.

Answer (score 1):

I will make two suggestions:

1. The switch syntax allows you to execute the same code for multiple cases by falling through (omitting a `break` between one case and the next).

   ```
   switch ($string[0]) {
       case 'a':
       case 'b':
       case 'c':
           handle_A_B_C();
           break;
       case 'd':
       case 'e':
           handle_D_E();
           break;

       // ...etc.
   }
   ```
2. I like to use in_array() to do multiple equality comparisons in an elegant, readable way.

   ```
   if (in_array($string[0], ['a', 'b', 'c'])) {
       handle_A_B_C();
   } elseif (in_array($string[0], ['d', 'e'])) {
       handle_D_E();
   }
   // ... etc.
   ```

As noted by @devon below, you can substitute `range('a', 'c')` for `['a', 'b', 'c']` for readability. If you have cases that fire on more than two or three letters and the letters are always sequential, that would be a nice touch.

Comment: Good example of using in_array.  I think it'd be easier to keep them organized in arrays in the long run.  Keep in mind, you can also use range() to generate an array for alphabetical characters.

Comment: Oh, I had forgotten that range() supported that. I'll add that note to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can stack cases, however, you also want to be careful of using break.  Break means it won't check any additional cases.  If 'c' can perform both x() and y(), you'll want something like this:

```
switch ($string[0]) {
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
    case 'c':
        x();
    case 'c':
    case 'd':
        y();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, this also can be used, by defining a map/legend array and looping through it.

```
/*
Define legends function as a key,  letters array as value
*/
$legend=array (
    'process_abc'=>array('a','b','c'),
    'process_gpo'=>array('g','p','o')
);

/*
    loop through the legend and check if it exists within the array
*/
foreach ($legend as $function=>$letters){
     if (in_array($string[0],$letters)){
        call_user_func($function);
        break;
     }
}


function process_abc(){
    echo "ABC was called";  
}

function process_gpo(){
    echo "GPO was called";  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use the switch like this:

```
$char = 'z';
switch (true) {
    case strpos('abcdef', $char) !== -1:
        echo 'Do A';
    break;
    case strpos('ghijkl', $char) !== -1:
        echo 'Do B';
    break;
    case strpos('mnopqr', $char) !== -1:
        echo 'Do C';
    break;
    case strpos('stuvw', $char) !== -1:
        echo 'Do D';
    break;
    case strpos('xyz', $char) !== -1:
        echo 'Do E';
    break;
}
```

Or group the `case`s:

```
switch ($char) {
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
    case 'c':
        echo 'Do A';
    break;
    case 'd':
    case 'e':
    // ...
        echo 'Do B';
    break;
    // ...
}
```

Or this:

```
$actions = [
    'abcde':  function () { return 'Do A'; },
    'fghij':  function () { return 'Do B'; },
    'klmno':  function () { return 'Do C'; },
    'pqrst':  function () { return 'Do D'; },
    'uvwxyz': function () { return 'Do E'; },
];
$char = 'n';
foreach ($actions as $haystack => $callback) {
    if (strpos($haystack, $char) !== -1) {
        echo $callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP's `strpos()` NEVER returns `-1`.  `switch (true) ` is an antipattern that removes the only advantage that a switch block has over an if block -- a single evaluation.